# Jquery Organization Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My organization chart has testing and developing teams. One employee(Tester) is working in both teams so I would like to combine developing team tree to testing team tree. I worked out     **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/porgzctr/4/)** but no use please help me

**HTML**

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul id="testing">
    <li parent-id=0 emp-id=1>Rao</li>
    <li parent-id=1 emp-id=2>Venkat</li>
    <li parent-id=2 emp-id=3>Ragava</li>
    <li parent-id=3 emp-id=4>Basha</li>
    <li parent-id=3 emp-id=5>Tester1</li>
    <li parent-id=5 emp-id=6>Tester1a</li>
    <li parent-id=5 emp-id=7>Tester1b</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="development">
    <li parent-id=0 emp-id=8>Vengal</li>
    <li parent-id=8 emp-id=9>Naren</li>
    <li parent-id=9 emp-id=5>Tester1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$ul.find('li[parent-id]').each(function() {
  $ul.find('li[parent-id=' + $(this).attr('emp-id') + ']').wrapAll('<ul />').parent().appendTo(this)
});
```

for complete view see the     **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/porgzctr/4/)**

[image]

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: @winner_joiner Image uploaded please check

Comment: show only one Tester node instead of two. simply to say Tester1 had two parent then how to generate the view.

Comment: Since the lines are drawn with css borders, an the `ul` structure, I think that what you want is not possible(easy). Since you cannot merge two list. You would have to change the CSS.

Comment: best solution would be create the `html` structure or layout you want to see and that see how to construct it with jQuery or so. Abit like this https://jsfiddle.net/porgzctr/10/  (I know this is not what you where after, but like this I would start looking for the solution)